# How to set a countdown timer to hourly

Tags: c#, timer

From my understanding, interval is based on miliseconds in c#. However, I would wish to set my timer based on hourly.

How do I do so? Do I change the interval under the timer properties to `3600000`?

Comment: From my experience, if you have a solution like you do then you just need to try it. What you suggested will work.

Comment: I would write it as `60 * 60 * 1000; // one hour` so that when you read the code a couple of years from now it will be clear without having to do the reverse math in your head. anyway your calculation seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes

but you can use something like

```
int hour = 1;
int setinterval = hour * 60 * 60 * 1000;
timerName.Interval = setinterval;
```

Comment: if I were to use this method, must I set the interval properties under the timer to be 1000 too? because I tried putting interval as 0 and it showed me invalid value

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
("YourCountdownTimer").Interval = 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the readability of your code, you could use [System.TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan) to clarify your intent:

```
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(2).Milliseconds
```

This will set the interval of the timer to 2 hours.